# kivy Screen Manager and popup

Tags: python, kivy

I have a app in kivy with a screen manager and a popup within it. The popup works until the point I put a button with the close function into the popup window. At this point i get the message:

```
PopupException: Popup can have only one widget as content
```

There is another post on this topic but it does not seem to work.

The python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ContentScreen(Screen):

    def open_popup(self):
        the_popup = CustomPopup()
        the_popup.open()

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("am.kv")

class AMApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AMApp().run()
```

The kivy file is below. The issue seems to come in the button function when calling the custompop

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    ContentScreen:

<CustomPopup>:
    size_hint: .5 , .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "The Popup"
    Button:
        text: "Close"
        on_press: root.dismiss()

<MainScreen>:
    name: "Welcome"
    Button:
        text: "First Screen"
        size_hint: 1, .5
        font_size: 40
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}
        on_release: app.root.current = "other"

    Button:
        text: 'Welcome Mr and Mrs Shaw'
        size_hint: 1, .5
        font_size: 25
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
        on_release: app.root.current = "other"

<ContentScreen>:
    name: "other"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_x: .22
        Button:
            text: "open Popup"
            on_press: root.open_popup()
```

Comment: The code posted above runs fine without error.

Comment: For me it crashed when the popup button was pressed, but was fine up until that point

Comment: Please provide the following: OS, Kivy version, Python version. Thank you.

Comment: kivy: 2.2, python: 3.7, OS 1803

Answer (score 0):

The code posted above, runs fine on Linux Buster, Kivy 1.11.0-dev and 1.10.1, and Python 3.7.3rc1

## Solution

Try adding a layout e.g. `BoxLayout` into `CustomPopup` to solve the `PopupException`.

## Example

The following example illustrates a popup window with a message and a button.

### Snippets

```
<CustomPopup>:
    size_hint: .5 , .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "The Popup"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: "Hello Kivy"
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            on_press: root.dismiss()
```

Comment: What is your OS i.e. Mac OS, Windows, Ubuntu, etc?

Comment: it is windows 10

Comment: Try uninstall Kivy 2.2 and install Kivy 1.10.1. [User’s Guide » Installation on Windows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#installation)

Comment: I was able to add text hello kivy in but it still doesn't like to close it down

Comment: It should close the `Popup` window when you click on the *Close* `Button`. Could you please show your updated code.